# SSRS Multi-Value Parameter no default no longer working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My 2008R2 reports have cascading parameters that ultimately determine which "selections" are selected by default in the final parameter.  This report has worked for months as the number of possibilities in the last parameter has been growing as our company has been signing on more business.

Today all of my subscriptions broke with the error:  *The subscription contains parameter values that are not valid.*

When I looked at the report subscriptions I noticed that the report is no longer loading the default selection of all.  The # of items in that drop-down is 1,890.  Yesterday, the last day it worked, the # was 1,876.  The value being loaded in for each selection is 8 characters long.

Is there a limit that I've surpassed for the default to be selected?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit for the size of multi-value parameters. I believe it is related to the total length of the selected parameters. [One source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/89ca7b3d-80f1-4a4f-b8c7-df1f377132e3/length-and-count-limitations-of-a-multivalued-text-parameters-in-ssrs-2008) says it maxes out at 7062 characters. But I suspect the formula might be more complex than that and related to other parameters as well.

Either way, sounds like you've passed the limit.

If users are always just accepting the default, then you could code that into the query directly instead of a parameter.

Comment: The parameters are there, it just won't select them as default.  I had the MaxHttpCollectionKeys set to 10000 and upped it to 50000.